# IOException in mReferrerClient.getInstallReferrer() with HMS Core version 5.0.1.307

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, install-referrer, huawei-developers, huawei-ads

I want to test my own app before going live after integrating with Huawei install Referrer SDK. I followed all the steps found in codelabs and the documentations and when i install the apk on the device , getInstallReferrer method throws IOException. This is my code. What is it that i am doing wrong ?. how can i get installReferrer info for testing purposes ?

```
       Runnable {
            referrerClient = newBuilder(context).setTest(true).build()
            referrerClient.startConnection(object : InstallReferrerStateListener {

                @SuppressLint("SwitchIntDef")
                override fun onInstallReferrerSetupFinished(responseCode: Int) {
                    when (responseCode) {
                        InstallReferrerClient.InstallReferrerResponse.OK -> {
                            // Connection established.
                            try {
                                val response: ReferrerDetails = referrerClient.installReferrer
                                val referrerUrl: String = response.installReferrer
                                val referrerClickTime: Long = response.referrerClickTimestampSeconds
                                val appInstallTime: Long = response.installBeginTimestampSeconds
                            }catch (e : IOException){
                                Log.i("INSTALL_REFERRER","IOException")
                            }
                            catch(e: RemoteException){
                                Log.i("INSTALL_REFERRER","RemoteException")
                            }
                            finally {
                                referrerClient.endConnection()
                            }


                        }
                        InstallReferrerClient.InstallReferrerResponse.FEATURE_NOT_SUPPORTED -> {
                           
                            Log.i("INSTALL_REFERRER","NOT AVAILABLE")
                        }
                        InstallReferrerClient.InstallReferrerResponse.SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE -> {
                           
                            Log.i("INSTALL_REFERRER","SERVICE UNAVAILABLE")
                        }
                    }
                }

                override fun onInstallReferrerServiceDisconnected() {
                    Log.i("INSTALL_REFERRER","ReferrerServiceDisconnected")
                }
            })
        }.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether the AIDL interface is added.

Check the screenshot below:
[image]

- **Obtain Install Referrer Information by AIDL**

You can call an AIDL API provided by HUAWEI Ads Kit to obtain install referrer information from HUAWEI devices, without integrating any HUAWEI SDK. The install referrer information obtained from a device in either mode (SDK or AIDL) is the same.

- **Call Process**
  [image]
- **The Development Procedure is as follows**

1. Create an AIDL file for the IPPSChannelInfoService API and save the file.
2. Copy the following content to the AIDL file:

   package com.huawei.android.hms.ppskit;
   /** Important: Do not change the method sequence in the AIDL file. */
   interface IPPSChannelInfoService {
   String getChannelInfo();
   }
3. Change Build Action to AndroidInterfaceDescription of AIDL file.
4. Rebuild project.
5. Create a class to implement Android-native IServiceConnection.

For more details, see [docs](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides-V1/obtaining-install-referrer-information-0000001050178565-V1).
Also, please kindly refer to [the demo](https://github.com/HMS-Core/hms-codelabs/tree/master/Ads%20Kit%20(Install%20Referrer)).

**Update:**

1. The package name needs to be specified because `setTest(true)`

   if (this.isTest){
   var2 = "com.huawei.pps.hms.test";
   }
2. The empty check on `ReferrerDetails` can be added.

   if (null != referrerDetails && null != mCallback)

Comment: as i understood from the documentation, AIDL method is another way of implementing InstallReferrer but not a completion for the first method (the SDK method) . Am i missing something?

Comment: @YomnaGamal Yes, I update my answer. Please check your package name  "com.huawei.pps.hms.test". And please add the empty check on ReferrerDetails.

Comment: I have checked the demo link but I found out that his application package name is the one you mentioned but how could i change my application package name knowing that it is already live on app gallery ?

Comment: @YomnaGamal The package name cannot be changed if it is already on App Gallery, unless you create a new one on the AGC. And you don't need to. Here is the thing, if you setTest(true) , your package name should be "com.huawei.pps.hms.test" ,and that's for test . To get get intall referrer of your own app , you need to publish your app in Huawei App Gallery, and download your app . If you have any more questions, feel free to contact me.

Comment: @YomnaGamal I have the same problem. I try launch two test project on my Honor 10, https://github.com/huaweicodelabs/Ads/tree/master/InstallReferrer and https://github.com/HMS-Core/hms-codelabs/tree/master/Ads%20Kit%20(Install%20Referrer) In both cases i get `getInstallReferrer IOException: getInstallReferrer not found installreferrer`. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong

Comment: @ВладиславПрасков hey! did you figure out what was wrong?